# Titanium namespaces (preventing acces nested namespaces functions)

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, javascript-namespaces

I have my project defined almost the same as this one: https://github.com/krawaller/Struct/tree/master/Resources

But the problem I'm having is that I can still access objects from S on any depth. I can for example access S.ui form app.js and so on. Can I prevent this?

I tried using revealing module pattern but because of Ti.include I can see the objects globally...

If I do Ti.include inside function scope, are loaded/included objects bound to this function scope or nor?

Any samples/examples on this problem?

Comment: I found an aswer about Ti.include... Seems it's not affected by scope it is run in... Any other solutions than multiple contexts?

Comment: other than that, I don't know of any other solutions. Be aware of the fact that if you to Ti.include, the use of memory will rise.